# Reuse anonymous variable within select statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
db.opt.Select(z => new { 
    z.QuestionTitle,
    Count = z.Responces.Where(x => x.Responseval == Constants.options.Agree).Count(),
    Perc = (totresponcecount/Count)*100
}).ToList();
```

In the above lambda, while calculating percentage for eg I want to write `(totresponcecount/Count)*100` where `Count` is already calculated in above statement.

So how can I access `Count` value to write `Perc = (totresponcecount/Count)*100`?

Comment: What's the type of `totresponcecount`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise to use one more select statement to save this variable:

```
db
    .opt
    .Select(z => new
    {
        z.QuestionTitle,
        Count = z.Responces.Where(x => x.Responseval == Constants.options.Agree).Count()
    })
    .Select(z => new
    {
        z.QuestionTitle, 
        z.Count,
        Perc = (totresponcecount / z.Count) * 100
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This will not have any impact on performace?

Comment: @user3815413 this is equivalent of the answer you accepted, because `let`  is really transformed to additional Select (just like in this answer).

Answer (score 5):

I think in this case query syntax is nicer using the `let` keyword:

```
var result = from z in db.opt
             let count = z.Responces.Count(x => x.Responseval == Constants.options.Agree)
             select new { z.QuestionTitle, count , Perc = (totresponcecount/count) * 100 };
```

*Also notice that you can pass a predicate to the `Count` method so no need for `Where(...).Count()`.*